# facing issue with link in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new to wordpress...

I have downloaded complete wordpress project from my online website via ftp then take the backup copy of the online database. I have put the database in my local machine in mysql. with the help of phpmyadmin i have modified the links in wp_post of site url and home and put my complete backup of website on local webserver.
every where link is working properly but on first page on one link it shows me the content is linked to online. and when i click on the link then it get directed to my online site. and not working from offline.
How can I change it to run on my local system.

Comment: shouldn't this be in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check the wordpress DB tables for the links, they still contains the online URLs.

Check the 'wp_posts' table for the 'guid' field.

Comment: I have checked the wp_posts and now everything is working fine....... Thanks.....